# How can I detect when the screen resolution changes?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl-es

I have written an OpenGL application that is always rendering full-screen.  Occasionally I switch displays while the app is running, (physically connect a different monitor or projector) which may also result in a change of resolution.  How can I detect when the display has changed resolution so that I can update my OpenGL output window, and adapt the content to the new resolution?

What I'm looking for is an event or signal of some kind that I can observe when the display mode changes due to a different physical display being connected.

I expect there's probably some way of getting notified - maybe it's an xlib thing?  Just not sure where the event or signal might come from.

I'm working in OpenGL ES, C++, Linux ARM (aarch64).

Comment: The OpenGL API isn't concerned with things like your desktop/monitor resolution. *You tell it* the resolution to render at, it can't tell you. Then the image that comes back is handled by your OS's display manager or desktop environment. On Linux, the X display manager is a good place to start looking for a way to listen for resolution changes. (Libraries like GLFW abstract this separation of concerns away and implement this for you, consider using one.)

Comment: Opengl is generally hosted by a native window object. You need to use the notification mechanisms of that window to handle these types of updates. Try to encapsulate this code to it is easy to port to a different platform. if you really want to remain platform independent, you could use Qt as your windowing provider, but that is generally too much for a few simple notifications.

Comment: @GemTaylor, currently the window does not resize when the screen resolution changes, so nothing changes about the window, so there is nothing to observe in terms of notifications.  Maybe your proposal could lead to a solution, but I don't know what to do.